# Netlify form leading to 404

Tags: reactjs, typescript, netlify

I just want an email input field from my users for my site. I am using TypeScript, React, Vite, and Tailwind. I followed all the documentation provided from Netlify on the forms. Nothing is working. I tried with an `onSubmit`, without, with `netlify` attribute, with `data-netlify`, and nothing seems to work. Without the `onSubmit`, it leads me to a `404` not found.
[image]
[image]

here is my code:

```js
        <form
          name="modalcontact"
          method="POST"
          action="/"
          data-netlify="true"
          data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
          // onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
          className="flex flex-col gap-4"
        >
          <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="modalcontact" />
          <label className="flex flex-col" htmlFor="email">
            Email:
            <input
              className="py-3 px-6 rounded-md text-DarkGrey outline-none border-none shadow-md"
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter Email..."
            />
          </label>
          <LimitlessButton className="w-full" type="submit" text={"Submit"} />
        </form>
```

Comment: which Netlify CLI command did you run (is it `yarn netlify dev`?)? and what is the output?

Comment: @Raptor Netlify auto deploys from each branch push since its connected on github